# Couldn't come up with a code to answer this query .

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, join

SQL> select * from displayed_on;

```
    ID NAME
```

---

```
     2 History of Art
     4 History of Art
     1 Berserk Charity
     5 Berserk Charity
```

SQL> select * from Art_Object;

```
    ID YEAR                      TITLE                     DES                       A_NAME
```

---

```
     1 1890                      Old Man                   An old man in the dark    van Gogh
     2 1894                      Cat                       White cat in black canvas van Gogh
     3 1853                      Monalisa                  Smiling woman             Leonardo
     4 1888                      The meeting               Two men talking           Picaso
     5 2017                      The crimson stone         Group of characters       Omar
```

SQL>

*And the query they asks me is (Display the number of art objects being exhibited now per artist.) being exhibited means they are in the " displayed_on" table.*

Comment: select count(ID) from Art_Object group by (A_NAME);

Comment: I’m sure you’ll be able to figure out how to select multiple fields in a query by yourself. Hint: google

Answer (score 2):

Just `JOIN` the two tables with group by and count:

```
SELECT
  o1.A_Name,
  COUNT(COALESCE(o2.ID, 0)) AS TotalNOfObjects
FROM Art_Object as o1
LEFT JOIN displayed_on AS o2 ON o1.ID = o2.ID
GROUP BY o1.A_Name;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8e61c0/1)**:

```
|   A_Name | TotalNOfObjects |
|----------|-----------------|
| Leonardo |               1 |
|     Omar |               1 |
|   Picaso |               1 |
| van Gogh |               2 |
```

Comment: what if i need to display how many art objects per category? , like how many art object in painting + in sculpture + in other and display the count in one table? @Win Cc

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
select count(ID), A_NAME 
from Art_Object 
where ID in (select ID from displayed_on) group by (A_NAME);
```

Comment: The sub query isn’t necessary at all

Comment: The question clearly says "being exhibited means they are in the " displayed_on" table."

Comment: @Omar.K Try now

Comment: tried yours , and added the artist name : select A_name,count(id) from Art_Object where id in (select id from displayed_on) group by (a_name);

Comment: Thank you both @Arvindsinc2 and Baao

Comment: what if i need to display how many art objects per category? , like how many art object in painting + in sculpture + in other and display the count in one table?

Comment: @Omar.K i am sorry..i dint get you...could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Arvindsinc2 it's ok i got it, thank you for the help